# Dealing with React re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, caching, rendering, browser-cache

I come to you experts not for a solutions but for some advice...

I'm making a webapp with React JS, in some point it has a list that I build by chunks (20 items each) that I request to my backend when the user reach 80% of the list (so far so good).

When I click at one of the items on the list it goes to another page with the item detail.

Now the problem...

When I go back my app renders like the first time and I lose the index.

Imagine you're navigating on a website that shows a huge list of photos and you want to see the details of the photo number 300 and when you go back it shows you the list starting at photo number 1. It's going to be tedious and create confusion to the end users when this happens.

I was thinking to implement some kind of cache but I don't know if React accepts this kind of strategies or if maybe there's a better approach to attack this problem.

Please I will appreciate any idea, I know some of you already dealt with this.

Answer (score 0):

You used Router, right? 
So it is the normal way REACT runs. 
In VUE, the property `keep-alive` may be what you want. But for REACT, you need to search for third-part libraries on npm repo.
What you need is to save all the state the previous routed component has, or instead, to save the whole instance some where.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using react router, check https://github.com/oaf-project/oaf-react-router. I used it for the same purpose.